# Actualização de uma datagrid com ligação a mysql

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, odbc

Não consigo actualizar uma tabela de uma base de dados ligada a uma datagrid. Quando altero os dados nas células da datagrid, apesar destes aparecerem alterados durante o debug, no final a tabela não é actualizada. Alguém sabe o que falta no código?

```
private static OdbcConnection CreateConnection()
{
    return new OdbcConnection("driver= {MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=192.168.20.29; database=yyyy; uid=esta; password=1234; option = 3 ");
}
using (OdbcConnection connection = CreateConnection())
{
string CmdText = "update lojas set Bloqueado =@bloqueador, DataFim = @DataFim, Nome = @Nome where Id =@Id";

OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand(CmdText, connection);
cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
connection.Open();

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloqueador",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFim",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);

cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

Comment: Veja se isso te ajuda.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526067/c-sharp-refresh-datagridview-when-updating-or-inserted-on-another-form

Comment: Ou isso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting

Comment: Esse código está num botão? Se não, onde ele é disparado?

Answer (score 1):

Aconselho a utilização de Mysql.data você pode pegar a dll [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), utilizando ele ficará mais fácil, segue exemplo de conexão com o banco e update do mesmo:

```
bdConn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;server=SERVIDOR;database=BANCO;uid=LOGIN;pwd=SENHA");
try
{
    bdConn.Open();
    MySqlCommand updateCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lojas SET Bloqueado =@bloqueador, DataFim = @DataFim, Nome = @Nome WHERE Id =@Id", bdConn);
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bloqueador",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DataFim",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value);
    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome",grid_lic.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value);
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    //Fechar conexão aberta
    bdConn.Close();
}
```

É aconselhável abertura e fechamento de conexão para todas as consultas que você irá realizar (também é aconselhável realizar o máximo de consultas que você puder com está conexão para economizar tempo em processo de abertura e fechamento de conexão com o banco).

Comment: mas não é exatamente, exceto pelo tratamento de exceção, o que acontece na implementação do Dispose Pattern através do using?